# PointerClick only works once

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine, eventtrigger

I have a problem & it's annoying me.

I have a prefab that containing just one UI Image (supposed to be square). I'm trying to create (via script) many of them (Like 5x5 or 10x10). I added a pointerClick event with eventTrigger for detect click & print the clicking objects' name. But there is a problem. PointerClick event only works once. It is supposed to give result for every click. Thanks for helping.

Here is my prefabs' photo & my scripts:

[prefab_photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPC35.png)

Creation

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class gameSlots : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject gameSlot;
public int gameLevel=5;
void Start(){
    gameLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("levelSelect");

    RectTransform gameTable=gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    float width = gameTable.rect.width/gameLevel;

    for (int i=0; i<gameLevel; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<gameLevel;j++){
            GameObject slot=(GameObject)Instantiate(gameSlot);
            slot.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform,false);
            slot.name=(i+1)+"-"+(j+1);

            RectTransform rectTrans = slot.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            float x= -gameTable.rect.width/2 + width*i;
            float y= gameTable.rect.height/2 - width*j-width;
            rectTrans.offsetMin=new Vector2(x,y);
            x= rectTrans.offsetMin.x + width;
            y= rectTrans.offsetMin.y + width;
            rectTrans.offsetMax=new Vector2(x,y);
        }
    }
}
```

script for PointerClick event

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class slotCheck : MonoBehaviour {
   public void name(){
       Debug.Log (transform.name);
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't see any event or event handler here.

Comment: all game object will be created on same position? why dont you re-position them? if you use 2d Camera, you cant see them clearly

Comment: Actually all gameobjects positioning on an empty gameobject like a matrix. In this [photo](http://s30.postimg.org/5s8nbb6n5/wats.png), you can clearly see what i tried. I need every images' name in every click